# I'm trying to .load() only 1 div but all content is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to .load() only 1 div of content.html (#tabs-1, #tabs-2) but all the page is loaded when class .button has been clicked.

```
<li><a class="button" id="tabs-1" >Option 1</a></li> 
<li><a class="button" id="tabs-2">Option 2</a></li>

<div id="container"></div>
```

---

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var id = $('this').attr('id');
    var url = "content.html#";
    $('#container').html(" ");
    $('#container').load(url + id);
});
```

**content.html**

```
<div id="tabs-1">
   CONTENT 1 CONTENT 1  CONTENT 1  
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
   CONTENT 2 CONTENT 2 CONTENT 2  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `.load()`, because it's doing what it is supposed to. What have you tried to only load a div from within the loaded page?

Comment: now check answer solved your problem...

Answer (score 1):

To get the clicked elements id, you can use `this.id`, you are trying to get the id of an element with tag `this` like `<this id="x">..</this>`

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    var url = "content.html #"
    $('#container').html("").load(url + this.id);
});
```

Comment: from where id is coming??

Answer (score 0):

it should be like below :-

```
 $('.button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = 'content.html("#';
    $('#container').html(" ");
    $('#container').load(url + id + '")');

  });
```

Comment: edited the answer try to do now i havnt chcked though

Answer (score 0):

Change **'this'** to **this** only and use `preventDefault` like

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();// preventing default working
   var id = $(this).attr('id');// this instead of 'this'
   //var id = this.id; // you can use it simply using core javascript
   var url = "content.html#";
   //$('#container').html(" "); //no need to do this
   $('#container').load(url + id);// load will remove previous data
});
```

Comment: done, but is not working yet, I can not make it work

Comment: @erichmuller use `e.preventDefault();` check my `answer` once again.

Comment: preventDefault does nothing, both divs still load at the same time when .button is clicked

Comment: @erichmuller 
In your **content.html** page you have to `code` for which `tab`, `data` to be show or use any `server side script` like **PHP**, Your code will show both `divs tab-1 and div-2 data`

Answer (score 0):

```
var html1='';
var html2='';

html1='<div class="tabs-1">CONTENT 1 CONTENT 1  CONTENT 1  </div>';
html2='<div class="tabs-2">CONTENT 2 CONTENT 2 CONTENT 2  </div>';

$('.button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(id == "tabs-1"){
         var html = html1;
        }else{
         var html = html2;
        }
        $('#container').html("");
        $('#container').html(html);
    });
```

I changed id because id always unique.

Comment: not working yet, Firebug says
GET content.html 200 OK 15ms

should it say content.html#tabs-1 or content.html#tabs-2 ?

Comment: updated try it and if possible then add jsfiddle demo and one more thing you can't set same id's , it always unique you can use class more then one time in a single page but not an id